# Create react app and debug in VS Code in wsl ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, create-react-app, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-debugger, chrome-debugging

I'm trying to debug my CRA app running in WSL with VS Code and running into a very strange result.
If I set a breakpoint in VS Code - it doesn't work at all.
If I go to developer tools in chrome -> source -> `localhost:3000/home/user/project/src/components/Component` I set breakpoint there and then see that same file in VS Code, but the path of the file is weird `\home\user\project\src\components\Component`

I believe there's something wrong with source maps but cannot figure out what exactly.
If I run same code in Windows breakpoints are working.

Did anyone have any experience debugging in VS Code in WSL ? Any thoughts on that problem maybe ?

Comment: This is probably related to this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/832

Answer (score -3):

The wsl container has it's own filesystem, so you need remote wsl debugging extension.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Use Linux @eugene-monakoff

Comment: This answer is no help at all.